# How can I count the number of posts & comments in a SharePoint 2013 newsfeed?

Tags: 2013, powershell, web-analytics, reports, newsfeed

I need to count the number of posts & comments in a SharePoint 2013 newsfeed webpart on a page in a site.

At the moment I can't see how to do this via Site Settings -> Report or Site Settings -> Popularity Trends.  I'm happy to do it via PowerShell if necessary.

I've read a lot online about how SharePoint 2013 web-based analytics/reporting is considered to be a big step back compared to what was provided in SharePoint 2010.

There's also a surprising lack of sample PowerShell scripts for SharePoint 2013 analytics, and pretty much most of the 2010 analytics related scripts don't work in 2013.

Any help & pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for the same type of functionality. Have you found a way to track these?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am still looking.  There must be some PowerShell code out there somewhere but I can't find it via Google.

Comment: It's 2019 and i am looking for the same thing. Have you found a solution for this?